# a doubt on the left ideal of the matrix ring in Dummit&Foote's Abstract Algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, matrices, ring-theory, ideals

I have a doubt in Dummit's Abstract Algebra on page245 :

"For each $j\in[1,2,\dots,n]$ let $L_j$ be the set of all $n\times n$ matrices in $M_n(R)$ with arbitrary entries in the $j^{\text{th}}$ column and zeros in all other columns."

> By the argument above, any matrix in $L_j$ must be of the form as follows:
> $$
> A=\begin{bmatrix}
>  \ 0&\cdots&0&a_{1j}&0&\cdots&0\ 
>  \\\ 0&\cdots&0&a_{2j}&0&\cdots&0\ 
>  \\\ \vdots&&\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&&\vdots\ 
>  \\\ 0&\cdots&0&a_{(n-1)j}&0&\cdots&0\ 
>  \\\ 0&\cdots&0&a_{nj}&0&\cdots&0\ 
> \end{bmatrix}
> $$
> where $a_{ij}\in R$ is arbitrary.

$\cdots\cdots$

"Moreover, $L_j$ is not a right ideal (hence is not a two-sided ideal). To see this, let $E_{pq}$ be the matrix with $1$ in the $p^{\text{th}}$ row and $q^{\text{th}}$ column and zeros elsewhere ( $p,q\in\{1,\dots,n\}$ ). Then ${\color{red}{E_{1j}\in L_j}}$ but $E_{1j}E_{ji}=E_{1i}\not\in L_j$ if $i\ne j$ , so $L_j$ is not closed under right multiplication by arbitrary ring elements."

> It is clear to see that
> $$
> E_{1j}=\begin{bmatrix}
>  \ 1&\cdots&1&1&1&\cdots&1\ 
>  \\\ 0&\cdots&0&1&0&\cdots&0\ 
>  \\\ \vdots&&\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&&\vdots\ 
>  \\\ 0&\cdots&0&1&0&\cdots&0\ 
>  \\\ 0&\cdots&0&1&0&\cdots&0\ 
> \end{bmatrix}
> $$
> is not in $L_j$ , which contradicts the red part in the context.

So is it a typo? And how to show that $L_j$ is not a right ideal by correcting the statement above?

Comment: Can you please stop titling your questions "a doubt on blah blah"?   Posts are all questions, they don't need stuff like "a question on", "a problem on" "a doubt on" in their titles.  You are more likely to get better attention by summarizing key phrases of your problem in the title.  In this case, even "a possible typo in D&F about left ideals of matrix rings" is better.

Comment: Your use of `>` is confusing. Normally it is used to quote material. But neither is all you quote block-quoted, nor is all you block-quote quoted material. In particular, the part "It is clear to see that..." seems to be your own material, not quotes from D&F. Please format your posts so that what you are quoting and what you are not quoting is clear.

Comment: OK, thanks for your advice, I will change my way of questioning next time.@rschwieb

Comment: I use the `>` to distinguish my ideas from the contents in D&F. I will break this habit later.@ArturoMagidin

Answer (score 2):

That's poor (imprecise) wording rather than a typo. A [matrix unit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_unit) $E_{pq}$ is a matrix that has all entries zero, except the *single* entry at the *intersection* (not union) of the $p$-th row and $q$-th column. This might indeed be confusing if you're for example self-studying and this is your first encounter with $E_{ij}$, especially since the book doesn't introduce the standard term for it right away.

Comment: Thanks! I remind the notation $E_pq$ that I had ever seen elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

He would have written *1's* if he had meant all entries in row i and column j, just like he then went on to use *zeros* aka '0's'. Notice the plural s.
Not poor wording but stringent style, which should be alright in a textbook on mathematics.

I think it's ok to say 'doubt about', 'doubt over' or 'doubt as to' something in this case. It indicates a question not about mathematics itself but a particular *text* on mathematics. Sort of a meta question.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Everything could be improved. For example, saying 'poor wording' about careful style.